# Choosing a compression algorithm to implement

Tags: c, encoding, compression, information-theory

I've been given some coursework to implement a compression algorithm of my choice. It can be any language, however the languages I know best would be Java, followed by C. It will be evaluated based on -

1. The decompressed output must match the original input, so I can only look at loss less algorithms.
2. The run time must be proportional to the length of the message.
3. The memory requirement must be independent of the length of the message.

Our implementations will be tested as follows -

1. A standard text file
2. A binary file with byte values from 0-255
3. A large file ~10mb of unspecified content.

My initial thought is to use dynamic arithmetic coding, but I'm wondering if there is an algorithm better suited to the constraints above? 
Secondly, is it a better idea to do it in C rather than Java? I ask this because I think C will have a smaller memory foot print but I'm unsure if that's actually the case.

I've spent some time Googling this question, and a few sites mention LZW coding combined with dynamic  Huffman coding. Would this be a sensible avenue to pursue? Our lecturer did warn us that 90% of the submissions that tried dynamic Huffman coding over the years were not correctly implemented.

That said, I'm not afraid to give it a try, but I would value some opinions before I begin.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: If 90% of prior submissions using Huffman were wrong, perhaps that makes it a better challenge for you.

Comment: Does Shannon-Fano not meet your (3) requirement? It's very simple to get right. If you've never implemented a compression algorithm before, I would suggest S-F.

Comment: If you do go the LZW-Dynamic-Huffman route, my only input is to use near-*anyone's* LZW technique *besides* the proposal set forth in [Dr.Dobbs 1989 article](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/lzw-data-compression/184408217). I found the "analysis" of Terry Welch's "mistake" in the algorithm and the author's "solution" to that problem insulting both to the reader and to Mr. Welch, who frankly has forgotten more about data compression algorithms than the author of that article will ever know.

Comment: Don't compress, just buy more disk space.

Answer (score 5):

Just LZW, with no other coding, is pretty darned simple and works surprisingly well.  No one would actually use LZW nowadays, since there are other algorithms that can compress better faster.  However for an assignment, you can't beat the simplicity of LZW.  No Huffman, dynamic or otherwise.  No Shannon-Fano.  No arithmetic or range coding.  And yes, the memory usage is independent of the length of the message.  Mark Nelson has written a [very good explanation](http://marknelson.us/1989/10/01/lzw-data-compression/).

You can do it in C or Java, though C might be less error-prone since it has unsigned types.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, Shannon-Fano should be "good enough" for such an assignment. If you've never done anything in the realm of data compression, I suggest staying away from Huffman coding (or specialized versions of arithmetic coding).

According to [this](http://www.stringology.org/DataCompression/sf/index_en.html), SF meets your space/time requirements. I suggest implementing something like that **first**. The pseudo-code is given by:

```
 1:  begin
 2:     count source units
 3:     sort source units to non-decreasing order
 4:     SF-SplitS
 5:     output(count of symbols, encoded tree, symbols)
 6:     write output
 7:   end
 8:  
 9:  procedure SF-Split(S)
10:  begin
11:     if (|S|>1) then
12:      begin
13:        divide S to S1 and S2 with about same count of units
14:        add 1 to codes in S1
15:        add 0 to codes in S2
16:        SF-Split(S1)
17:        SF-Split(S2)
18:      end
19:  end
```

Only if you thoroughly understand SF (or you've implemented similar algorithms prior) would I suggest going for a more rigorous arithmetic coding method. I recently implemented SF for a *Theory of Information* class and some parts of it seemed non-intuitive and weird until I got my head around it. On paper it looks simple, but (like numerous other algorithms) that can be deceiving.

Unless you get extra "style points" I would personally go for Shannon-Fano.

Comment: I can't use Shannon Fano for a few reasons. 
The first is that you have to sort the symbols into non increasing order of probability, so you would either have to make two passes in the file (one for analysis, one for compression) or read the entire file into memory. 

The second reason is the trees that it generates aren't always optimal. Even static Huffman Coding produces better results, and that's not difficult to implement.

Comment: @Saf: I know SF isn't optimal, but optimality wasn't on your list ;) I checked it thrice! Reading 10mb entirely into memory shouldn't be a problem; but if you can't use it, that's quite a bummer. It's a great introduction to Huffman/Arithmetic coding (as it's a special case of the latter).

Comment: I might use it as a fallback, or even as you suggested, a starting point. I would have to go with the scan the file twice though, loading the entire file would make the memory requirement proportional to the length of the message. I suspect I would be docked heavily for having to scan the file twice though, our lecturers tend to be all about the most efficient route. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Why do people put line numbers in these?

Comment: @RandyHoward: It's a direct copy-paste from the source I linked.

Answer (score 1):

The memory constraint suggests using an adaptive coding of some sort. Arithmetic coding is nice. But you haven't specified anything about performance. Does the algorithm have to hit any performance targets on a particular class of files? An algorithm that merely copies the file meets the requirements above, (but doesn't teach you much).

For the choice of language, use something you are more comfortable with. There are going to be a lot of bit manipulations to perform, so C or Java are both suited. You should write some code that handles turning files into bit streams and back again, and make that a separate module. I could see doing that in C or Java.

Comment: We don't have any performance target other than "as optimal as you can get working", vague I know, but I suspect that's part of the challenge. It should work well on any type file, so we don't have to worry about if the file is audio or video etc, other than possibly checking that we don't end up with information expansion

Comment: You should have learned in your class the theorem that no lossless compression method can compress all files. But it sounds like he is asking for a standard method of some sort. Also note that you are allowed 2 passes of the input file (2 times is still proportional). You're just not allowed to hold the whole file in memory.

Comment: We're only half way through the course, we started with the algorithms and are moving onto different type of files next, i.e. GIF, MP3 etc. But that's a good point, I'll ask the lecturer should it be optimised for a certain file type.